# How can I add condition in db raw laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, eloquent

My query db raw laravel like this :

```
public function getTopProduct($price = null) {
    $products =  DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT * 
                    FROM (
                        SELECT a.*, b.name AS store_name, b.address
                        FROM products a
                        JOIN stores b ON b.id = a.store_id
                        WHERE a.status = 1                                                
                    ) AS product
                    GROUP BY store_id')
        );
    return $products;
}
```

I want to add condition

If price is not null, it will add condition price on the `where`

For example, price = 1000, then the query on the `where` like this :

```
WHERE a.status = 1 AND a.price < 1000
```

If price = null, the condition `AND a.price < 1000` not executed

How can I do it?

**Update**

I slightly change my code flow

I try like this :

```
public function getTopProduct($price)
{
    if($price == 1)
        $price_condition = 'WHERE price > 1000';
    else if($price == 2)
        $price_condition = 'WHERE price >= 500 AND a.price <= 1000';
    else if($price == 3)
        $price_condition = 'WHERE price < 500';
    else
        $price_condition = '';


    $products = DB::select('SELECT * 
                    FROM (
                        SELECT a.*, b.name AS store_name, b.address
                        FROM products a
                        JOIN stores b ON b.id = a.store_id
                        WHERE a.status = 1                                                
                    ) AS product
                    GROUP BY store_id
                    '.$price_condition
                );
    return $products;
}
```

And it works

How do you think?

Whether my solution is correct? Or you have a better solution?

Comment: Take one variable with `$price=array_column($request->get('price'));` and make `->when` query with `where` condition! It execute when price is in request!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below code with your `where` condition:

```
$price = array_column($request->get('price'), 'id');
```

**OR**

`$price = $request->get('price');`

```
$query = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT * 
                FROM (
                    SELECT a.*, b.name AS store_name, b.address
                    FROM products a
                    JOIN stores b ON b.id = a.store_id
                    WHERE a.status = 1                                                
                ) AS product
                GROUP BY store_id'))
             ->when($price == 1, function($query) use ($price) {
                  $query->where('price', '>', '1000');
             })
             ->when($price == 2, function($query) use ($price) {
                  $query->where('price', '>=', '500')
                        ->where('a.price', '<=', '1000');
             })
             ->when($price == 3, function($query) use ($price) {
                  $query->where('price', '<', '500');
             })
             ->when($price == '', function($query) use ($price) {
                  $query->where('your_where_when_price_empty');
             })
             ->get();
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: What if using `DB:raw`?

Comment: It does not seem to help me. Try you see my case. Select, from, group by are inside db:raw. I want to add condition inside db:raw

Comment: You can do it in DB::raw! Place your code of DB::raw in my query and try it! I think it's work.

Comment: You try to update your answer according to my case. Because I'm still confused your answer

Comment: This : `DB::table('table_name')`. It does not seem necessary. Should `DB::select......`. And this : `$query->where('a.status = 1');`. Should `$query->where('a.price< 1000');`

Comment: Yes, you can start with DB::select()... Try with it and let me know if it works!

Comment: It does not works. There exist error : `Call to a member function when() on array`

Comment: This does not work for two reasons:
- The call to `DB::raw()` returns ` * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression raw($value)` which does not translate to `QueryBuilder`
- The call to `Db::select()` returns an array.
to which you cannot method chain `when`.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getTopProduct($price = null) {
if($price==null){
         $products =  DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT * 
                FROM (
                    SELECT a.*, b.name AS store_name, b.address
                    FROM products a
                    JOIN stores b ON b.id = a.store_id
                    WHERE a.status = 1                                                
                ) AS product
                GROUP BY store_id')
    );
 }else{
       $products =  DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT * 
                FROM (
                    SELECT a.*, b.name AS store_name, b.address
                    FROM products a
                    JOIN stores b ON b.id = a.store_id
                    WHERE a.status = 1 AND a.price='.$price.'                                                
                ) AS product
                GROUP BY store_id')
    );
 }
 return $products;
}
```

Comment: Can it add the condition inside the `DB:raw`? Because your code so long

Comment: Yes that would be sql condition not php condition

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Advanced Join Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins) in Query Builder

```
DB::table('products')
        ->join('stores', function ($join) use ($price) {
            $query = $join->on('stores.id', '=', 'products.store_id')
                          ->where('products.status', '=', 1);

            if (!empty($price)) {
                $query->where('products.price', '<', 1000);
            }
        })
        ->select('products.*', 'stores.name AS store_name', 'stores.address')
        ->groupBy('products.store_id')
        ->get();
```

Comment: How to add condition if it use `DB:raw` like my case?